# Pronunciation of “au” in restaurant

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

I thought that AU in French was always pronounced /o/, but  Collins dict (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/restaurant), Word Reference dict (https://www.wordreference.com/fren/restaurant) and Wiktionary (https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/restaurant) say that the AU in the French word "restaurant" is pronounced /ɔ/. Is that indeed the correct pronunciation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cannot say that the AU digraph (or the EAU trigraph ) is **always** pronounced /o/ in French. /o/ is only the **most common** pronunciation.
AU/EAU is indeed almost always pronounced /o/ when standing alone (*au*, *eau*) or at the end of a word (*bureau*, *beau*). But there can be regional differences. One of the source I give states that /ɔ/ can be heard at the end of a word in some eastern parts of France, Belgium and Switzerland.

When in the middle of a word we hear more varied pronunciations according to geographical areas. For example in France *gauche* would be pronounced [go:ʃ] by someone with a northern accent and [gɔ:ʃ] by someone with a southern accent. But when the AU digraph is followed by the consonant /ʁ/, the usual pronunciation, notwithstanding the origin of the speaker, is /ɔʁ/, therefore [ʁɛstɔʁɑ̃] being given in most dictionaries.

The most common pronunciation, of the name *Paul* is [pɔl] in all parts of France, whereas its feminine counterpart *Paule* is pronounced [poːl]. This has a historical reason: the name used to be written *Pol* and the pronunciation has survived the modified spelling.

Sources:
http://andre.thibault.pagesperso-orange.fr/PhonologieSemaine6.pdf
http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/Manuel_2011.html#6.15. (6.15. & 6.16)

Comment: Il est parfaitement clair pour moi en effet que je (au Qc.) ne prononce pas ce son de la même manière en comparant _restaurant_ et _resto_.

Comment: @suiiurisesse Same here. I (in France) say *resto/restau* [ʁɛsto]  (both spellings found this side of the Atlantic) but [ʁɛstɔʁɑ̃].

Comment: Même /ɔ/ ouvert dans restaurant et resto pour moi en Belgique, si tu voulais une confirmation de la présence du phonème en finale absolue de mot ici. D'ailleurs, la graphie resto est de loin préférée à restau, puisqu'elle représente mieux la prononciation locale

Comment: @Eauquidort Peut-être même qu'au Québec j'entends d'autres variations mais je sais pas si c'est marqué /œ/, /ə/ ou /ø/. Je suis incapable d'assimiler les différences que ça évoque.

Answer (score -2):

The standard pronunciation is /ɔ/; that's the pronunciation in the TLFi; it is then the same as that of "restaure" (/ɔ:/) and "restaurateur". Nevertheless, according to the same source, [-sto-] is a possibility for "restaurer".There must be cases of "au" being pronounced /o/ in "restaurant", as I find that my own pronunciation tends towards /o/.

By listening carefully to the "au" in the second source (wordreference) it can be noticed that while the sound is written /ɔ/, the actual pronunciation is very near that of /o/.

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "standard"?

Comment: I consider that if it is given by the TLFi it is  an ideal pronunciation, a dominant one that most people would like to impose as the unique pronunciation (so as to strive  towards uniformity), but I might not be quite right, as you seem to disagree.

Comment: My personal opinion is that there are several varieties of spoken French and that none is better than the other and should be "imposed". How dreary if we all looked and sounded alike!

Comment: @Laure You 're taking up the defence of diversity, I see … Yes, diversity has its points, but we've rejected the diversity of various ancient languages and we are quite glad in France not to have to speak both "la langue d'Oïl" and "la langue d'Oc". I don't think all pronunciations have the same merit; I've found a lot of people, themselves from the south of France, that would find heavy meridional accents rather substandard, accents to be abandonned. Although there is a matter of personal taste involved, I do believe in a "some theory" of superior accents (a very vague idea, though).

Comment: That's not vague, that's [supremacism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supremacism). It's not unusual for people who have been oppressed etc. by others to adopt their point of view about their superiority. In Quebec French we have a word pertaining to sociology which I find related to this phenomenon : [_colonisé_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/colonis%C3%A9) « Personne ayant assimilé et intégré une vision d'elle-même selon laquelle son groupe ethnique ou national est inférieur à un autre en particulier, ou aux autres en général. » I can't downvote a comment, otherwise I would yours.

Comment: @suiiurisesse You don't know what you are talking about, extrapolate, invent and finally come up with the most improbable assertions forgetting that people can think and have their personal ideas, not being bound to the leveller's vision you have of the world nor bound to follow your unthinking instincts when **they** abide by logical thinking and truth. Your methods are akin to those of Middle Age alchemy, 50 % invocation of the spirits, 50 % relying on homely instincts.